# Compare Values in same column for the same unique item updated at different times

Tags: sql, join, case, self-join

I am trying to build a report where I compare the data entry made by different individuals in a pipeline.

I want to filter for the instances where the entry was different.

So let's say my table has the following headers:

> user_id, group_id, attribute_name,    value_from, value_to, timestamp)

I am trying to get a  report which shows me the items(based on unique group_ids)

- which had a different value entered (identified by value_to)
- by users (identified by user_id)
- at different stages in the process (based on timestamp).

Also I only want to consider a few specific fields only (based on attribute_name, so something along the lines of ... attribute_name IN ('name', 'price',.....)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: I.e. [mcve]. Make it easy to assist you!

Answer (score 0):

The question is confusing due to lack of examples to show desired behavior. Based on my reading:

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM mystery_table_with_mystery_name
       t1
  JOIN (
         SELECT group_id
           FROM mystery_table_with_mystery_name
--------------- to filter rows BEFORE checking for multiple entries:
          WHERE attribute_name IN ( blah blah blah )
          GROUP
             BY group_id
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       )
       t2
    ON t2.group_id = t1.group_id
------ to filter rows AFTER output group_ids have been decided:
 WHERE t1.attribute_name IN ( blah blah blah )
```